# Reach HTML code inside another HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

[image]

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension and when I click the extension's button, I want to get the HTML inside the other `HTML` tag (in red in the picture above).
How can I achieve this?

Right now I only have implemented this:

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(
           tabs[0].id,
           {
              code: '' // what could I use there?
            },downloadFiles);

   });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: May you share an [mcve] of your efforts so far? The screenshot (next time use text) shows an iframe element, are you not able to use one?

Comment: Use [allFrames: true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: Thank you. The frame src is changing everytime and I cannot get that

Comment: Do you want to mess with the HTML tag in the background script or will you use it in the injected script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `html` selector to get the whole HTML:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(
           tabs[0].id, {
             code: `var htmlElement = document.querySelectorAll("html")[1];`
           },
       downloadFiles);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This way I get the first HTML, but inside that I have another one. How can I reach that? Tried double querySelector but it gives me null

Comment: @Dev9977 I added some code; You can use `querySelectorAll` and choose the index `1` or any other index.